# postinstall.py script is not executing after install msi in system which doesn't have python

Tags: python, batch-file, windows-installer, py2exe

I have created msi file using postinstall script and msi is installing in any system but postinstall script is not executing after installation.

This is my setup script code

```
setup(name='Proapp',
      version='1.0',
      py_modules=['App_New'],
      description='Project app',
      author='Ashish Jain',
      author_email='ashish@example.com',
      url='http://ashish-webmaster.blogspot.in/',
      packages=['Proapp'],
      scripts=['postinst.py'],
      package_data={'Proapp': ['*.pyd','*.dll','*.DLL','*.exe','images/*.*']},
      )
```

And after msi installation it is creating package like that

```
PythonX\
        Scripts\
                postinst.py
        Lib\
            sitepackage\
                        Proapp
```

And after msi installing in system postinst.py does not execute. from my opinion this file is not executing becoz python is not installed in this system and there is no python environment for executing.
Now my problem is how to execute postinst.py after msi install in system. I have checked with bat or vbs file but i am getting error at the time of installation,any other option for executing postinst.py or postinst.bat or vbs file for postinstall script.
Please help me for resolving it

Comment: What is the purpose of executing this script?

Comment: I am creating desktop shortcut icon and startup menu through this postinstall script.

Comment: Why not use the ShortCut table?  The problem with any kind of custom actions (such as a post install python script )  is you frequently end up reinventing the wheel with a less robust solution.  Use of the built in tables will automatically give you such things as rollback and uninstall.

Comment: Hi Christopher, I don't know about ShortCut tablein python. can you give information or link about it, so i can create msi with desktop shortcut key. I find about it but i didn't get much more.

Comment: Thanks Christopher for suggesting Shortcut table, I have created msi file with desktop shortcut key and there is no error but how to create Start menu here. PLZ let me know.

Comment: It's the same process you just use a different Directory property. StartMenuFolder or ProgramMenuFolder are frequently used. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370905(v=vs.85).aspx#system_folder_properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the ShortCut table? The problem with any kind of custom actions (such as a post install python script ) is you frequently end up reinventing the wheel with a less robust solution. Use of the built in tables will automatically give you such things as rollback and uninstall.